# Can FT232HL VCCIO be powered from external source?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, schematics, datasheet, ftdi

I would like to power the FT232HL from VBUS, but prevent it from supplying power through (UART) IOs to connected microcontroller. Microcontroller is powered from an external *+3V3* source, which might not be present when *VBUS* is present.

According to [datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232H.pdf), *VCCIO* is power supply for the IO Interface:

Symbol:

[image]

Pin definition:

[image]

And a note:

> **Note:** Failure to connect all VCCIO pins of the device will have unpredictable behaviour.

Supplying *VCCIO* from the microcontroller power supply makes sense, but the datasheet or application notes don't describe such possibility.

Can I have *VCCIO* powered externally to *+3V3* without providing other voltages to FT232H? That is the condition when USB is not plugged, but the circuit is powered on. Other option is to detect *VBUS* AND *+3V3* to provide power to *VCCIO*.

Comment: I acknowledge and understand that your question targets the possibility to only power the I/O banks while not powering the FT in total. However, May I ask what your ultimate goal is? Powering the FT but putting it in suspended mode is not sufficient for your application (i.e. Icc1s = ~330 µA too high; notice that no 5V is required for self powered mode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes, you can fully power the FTDI chip with only 3.3V from the MCU to build a self-powered USB device as depicted in datasheet Figure 6.3.

You can use external supply for VCCIO, but then it must be in self-powered mode, not bus-powered mode. You can't apply powers to half of the chip and be half-bus-powered and half-self-powered.

The problem is twofold, you don't want USB bus-powered FTDI to back-feed an unpowered MCU, and you also don't want the powered MCU to back-feed an unpowered FTDI chip.

If you specifically want the USB side to be fully bus-powered while allowing MCU to be unpowered, you need some isolation between the chips, such as logic buffers that can hande the situation. There are buffers that allow inputs to be present while being unpowered for example, or you could enable a buffer when voltages are fully present. The downside is, if one side is powered and the other isn't, the buffer may output a logic 0 to RXD pin, while it should idle at logic 1. Making a digital circuit where different parts are powered by different supply sources that may not be present is hard, and powered sectiond may power unpowered sections via data pins, which is of course not a good thing and should not be allowed.

Therefore I suggest to either change the whole device to be powered from the external supply, or via USB.

Comment: Using an external buffer would work, they can be configured to be disabled while the other source is missing, so the problem you described can be avoided. I just wonder if that's exactly what FTDI intended with the VCCIO, but haven't actually documented (tested?) it.

Comment: I also wouldn't want the FTDI chip to be unpowered while cable is attached.

Comment: @Ralph VCCIO pins are supply pins for the IO cells. They are separate pins so that IO currents do not disturb other sensitive parts inside the chip, such as VPHY or VPLL pins. And in self-powered mode you definitely will not be powering FTDI chip from USB cable, but from MCU board 5V or MCU board 3.3V. In that case USB 5V is only used for USB cable/host detection, just see figures 6.2 or 6.3 in data sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, The VCCIO just defined the logic levels of the outputs. You the FT232h has an internal regulator with two outputs, a 3.3V or 1.8V you could use either of those for VCCIO. Or you could use an external voltage. Make sure you use buffers on the outputs if powering the FT232h from the USB as the ports can source power and create power problems

Comment: But this is about powering every other supply node of chip via USB but only the VCCIO from MCU. I don't see that as a valid option in the data sheet (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: @Justme I didn't find it either, but the pins are 5 V tolerant and the VCCIO being exposed also in their eval board kind of suggests that there would be "buffering" feature on the IC. But without hard evidence I'll need to add another buffer...

Comment: @Ralph I ran into this same problem for the FT232RNL and had to add another buffer. I am not sure if this is the case for the 'h' part. I would put one on the board if cost isn't an issue. You could also do not loaded jumpers and put the buffer in and experiment.

Comment: The answer needs a bit editing. The VCCIO range is 2.97 to 3.63V even if IO cells are 5V tolerant. So technically the chip is meant for 3.3V +/- 10% VCCIO.

Answer (score 1):

Got a definite answer from FTDI support:

Unfortunately this use case is not viable.

See section 6 FT232H Configurations of the [FT232H Datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232H.pdf).
The design can only be USB bus powered of self-powered with no mixture of these modes.

VCCIO should be connected in one of the following configurations:

- Entirely bus powered, that is from the USB port (VREGIN and VCCIO pins). A local regulator is needed which can be supplied from the USB bus.
- Entirely self-powered, that is from the local supply on your board. Note that ACBUS7 is required to be connected to the USB Host 5V supply and the external EEPROM needs to be programmed to self-powered configuration.

VREGIN and VCCIO should be applied at the same time.
If VCCIO is not applied, the pin states will be unknown.
When VREGIN is off, do not apply any voltages to the IC pins.
There might be some current draw but this is not specified because the device can be in unknown states.